# Teradata: What field do I order by when querying dbc.DBQLogTbl to return SQL in chronological order?

Tags: teradata

There are several date/time fields in this view and I can never wrap my head around which column to order by (and which secondary column) in order to retrieve a list of SQL statements in the order in which they were executed on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**StartTime** - The timestamp associated with when the query was submitted to Teradata for parsing.

**FirstStepTime** - The timestamp associated with when the first step of the query was executed.

**FirstRespTime** - The timestamp associated with when the first row was returned to the client.

The gap in time between the StartTime and FirstStep time include parsing time and any workload throttle delay that was enforced by Teradata's Dynamic Workload Manager. For the sake for keeping things simple here I will defer to an excellent article written by Teradata's Carrie Ballinger on dealing with delay time [here](http://developer.teradata.com/blog/carrie/2012/07/intrepreting-dbql-delaytime-in-teradata-13-10).

Comment: Looks good!  I see you're SE's foremost (and apparently only) Teradata expert, so maybe you might want to try your hand at the question I just posted regarding deadlocks and how to debug them.